# How to hide dialog by checkbox?

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

How to hide the dialog box if the checkbox checked? i dont know how to do

[This is my dialog method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6TYB.jpg)

I tried to hide dialog box permanently by shared preference. But not working (my fault). So please give me the whole function

Comment: "give me the whole function"? SO is not meant to provide custom made code. You'll need to provide a lot more context of what you try to do and what you're actually doing, and what is failing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just want to close the dialog permanently if checked. Check the ss https://ibb.co/7SwQQgV and https://ibb.co/THw2gvH